# Can remote mobile testing of iOS apps through mobile labs deviceConnect be automated using tools like Selenium?

Tags: ios, selenium, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

We are manually testing iOS apps using Mobile Labs deviceconnect.
Mobile Labs deviceconnect helps us to access a physical ipad remotely through a link on a browser.

this is how it works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3j5RNK9MBY4

We have automated it using UFT. 
But we have decided to move to free tools.
Is it possible to automate it using Selenium, Appium or any other tools?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Labs deviceConnect supports most any automation tool using a software client called deviceBridge. This allows any device connected to deviceConnect to appear tethered to a tester's laptop. Open source (Selenium, Appium, Calabash, XCTest, Espresso, etc) or paid tools that require a tethered device can then be used for testing and development. In addition, Mobile Labs has integrated appium directly into deviceConnect making it a single point to run Selenium and Appium scripts in parallel against a wide range of devices.